# material ui : reactjs: TextField: Multiline: How to show minimum number of rows and after than no scroll

Tags: material-ui

In material ui Texfield for multiline. I want to show a minimum 3 rows in the beginning and there up expand the text area. I dont want to show scroll if the rows exceed 3

I tried this

```
        <TextField
          id="outlined-multiline-static"
          label="Multiline"
          multiline
          rows={3}
          defaultValue="Default Value"
          variant="outlined"
        />
```

What is see is

[image]

HOw to set min rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To increase the height, instead of showing scroll you can make use of maxRows prop instead. so the scroll would be added after the maxRows are reached
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-ccchw

```
<TextField
      id="outlined-multiline-static"
      label="Multiline"
      multiline
      rows={3}
      defaultValue="1"
      maxRows={10}
      variant="outlined"
    />
```

Comment: its `rowsMax` instead of `maxRows` may be typo. Thanks

Comment: Ok but its maxRows you can verify here https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/#multiline. might be a version change or something
Just check in the sandbox both works

Answer (score 0):

Add minRows to the TextField component

```
  <TextField
     id="outlined-multiline-static"
     label="Multiline"
     multiline
     rows={3}
     defaultValue="Default Value"
     variant="outlined"
     maxRows={3}
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a minimum number of lines using css, for example for 3 lines:

```
.MuiInputBase-inputMultiline{
    min-height: 70px;
}
```

and in  don't set any rows, only `multiline` attribute

```
<TextField
    id="outlined-multiline-static"
    label="Multiline"
    multiline
    defaultValue="Default Value"
    variant="outlined" />
```